# Corona iOS In-App purchase

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, coronasdk

Do i have to use the Store kit framework or does Corona already cover all that is needed, through using their iOS in-app purchase guide?

Or does Corona already cover everything that is required from the Store kit framework. Or do i have to do both?

Thank you

Comment: You can use the `InAppPurchase` sample from their sample code along with the SDK. It will do.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is create the actual In-App-Purchase information in the App Store Dev Portal.  Corona has In-App-Purchase sample code that you can view that takes your special secret keys and makes In-App-Purchases work within your app.

Check out this helpful tutorial: http://coronalabs.com/blog/2013/09/03/tutorial-understanding-in-app-purchases/